# Is there a way -- a rule of thumb procedure -- to deflate time series that is agreggated yearly without a yearly deflator?

Tags: time-series

Suppose I have yearly nominal data -- sales in US$ at the end of december -- and monthly CPPI. Since I cannot attain the right distribution of sales accross the months of the year, deflating the variables could produce different results in comparison to monthly data. Is there any discussion on this topic that could lend some help? My approach has been to use the yearly variation of CPPI, but I was trying to figure out how to approach this in order to approximate the value if I had monthly sales.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing it right.  If CPPI goes up 0.10% monthly, then it is about 1.2% annually (actually $(1+.001)^{12}-100$%)...what happens, along the way, is irrelevant if you don't have monthly sales data.

Of course, it could be that there were big spikes in monthly CPPI (followed by zero or even negative values), and monthly sales may be profoundly affected by that.  But you don't have that data, so it will all get averaged out.

In reality, it is unlikely to come out much different.  But you only know if you have the data.